# How to add an workflow association to a list

Tags: 2007, list, workflow, feature

I have a feature where I have create several items including lists and workflow. I want to add an workflow association to one of my lists. However I would like to refrain from using a code solution.

I have one list and one workflow added in the same feature.

I want to add an workflow association between them using the xml configuration.

This in on SharePoint 2007

Answer (score 3):

I have to admit to not knowing if this will work (it's not something I've tried or done before), but I came across an article in my searching about your problem that may be useful: http://parwejpathan.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/sharepoint-2010-workflow-association.html

Parwej appears to have created the workflow association manually and then saved the site as a template and then inspected the resulting template file by importing it into Visual Studio.  In there he found a WorkflowAssociation element which may help you get to where you want to go.  Take a read through his article and see if it helps.  Sorry I can't help more.

Comment: good find I think that is has put me on the right track.

Comment: sorry it seems this solution is for SharePoint 2010, I should have said I was looking for a 2007 solution.

Comment: my bad - you do mention it in your question: apologies (you're not the first question I've read where I've missed that obvious clue!!)

Answer (score 0):

After extensive search the only way to associate workflows in 2007 on a feature is it use a coded solution. There however WorkflowAssociation element for list schemas as you can see on list exported as templates with associations. However these are referencing a hardcoded .net object for the association with actual field names and values e.g. guids.

Code example of associating an workflow with a list can be found at [practices and guidance site for SharePoint 2007](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff800762.aspx) I cant post the code here because of the license on the guidance examples but they are free.